# JavaScript chaining method to function - TypeError: (intermediate value).methodName is not a function

Tags: javascript, method-chaining

I was following an online lesson for beginners, which used the apply/bind methods to set the 'this' context for a function.

I saw that you can chain the bind method directly to the function block, which was new to me. So it got me thinking why cant I chain other methods, other than bind/call/apply, to affect the returned value.

```
let obj = {
  name: 'john',
};

let sayHello = function() {
  return 'hello there ' + this.name;
}.apply(obj).toUpperCase();

let sayBonjour = function() {
  return 'Bonjour!';
}.toUpperCase();

console.log(sayHello);
console.log(sayBonjour());
```

In the example above why can I use the .toUpperCase() method on the sayHello function which uses the apply method, and not on the sayBonjour function which does not. In trying to do so I get the error:

'Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).toUpperCase is not a function'.

I realize this is not the way string method (or other methods) is/are intended to be used, for learning purposes, I was hoping someone could explain whats preventing me from using the method in such a way.

Many thanks for your time and help

Comment: The reason why you can use `bind`, `call` and `apply` but not `toUpperCase` is that there is no such method in `Function.prototype` (that is, there is no `Function.prototype.toUpperCase()`). Have a look at the list here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype. As `toUpperCase()` is a method present in `String.prototype` the IIFE in the answer below will work, since the function itself returns a string.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado The key word i was missing was 'call'. I was mistaken regarding the function being called or not, and so I was not applying the method to a returned string but to the function itself. Suddenly I understand the purpose of the call method perfectly now. Thankyou very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but you tried to use `.toUpperCase` on function. You can use it on string which will be returned by function expression. You can use [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to achieve this.

```js
let obj = {
  name: 'john',
};

let sayHello = function() {
  return 'hello there ' + this.name;
}.apply(obj).toUpperCase();

let sayBonjour = (function() {
  return 'Bonjour!';
})().toUpperCase();

console.log(sayHello);
console.log(sayBonjour);
```

Comment: I understand perfectly now regarding the use of an IIFE for this purpose. Thank you very much for your help. As a recap, I thought i was infact using the .toUpperCase() method on the returned string itself, but was mistaken. I have understood better the purpose of the call method which does just that, calls the function which then returned the string I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

This example shows what is happening when your code is exacuted.

```js
function print(value) {
 const str = Object.prototype.toString.apply(value);
 console.log("Type: " + str.slice(7, str.length - 1) + "\tValue: " + value);
}

let obj = {
 name: "john"
};
/*
let sayHello = function() {
 return 'hello there ' + this.name;
}.apply(obj).toUpperCase();
*/
// equals to
{
 console.log("sayHello case");
 let step1 = function () {
  return "hello there " + this.name;
 };
 print(step1);
 let step2 = step1.apply(obj);
 print(step2);
 let sayHello = step2.toUpperCase();
 print(sayHello);
}
/*
let sayBonjour = function() {
 return 'Bonjour!';
}.toUpperCase();
*/
// equals to
{
 console.log("sayBonjour case");
 let step1 = function () {
  return "Bonjour!";
 };
 print(step1);
 let sayBonjour = step1.toUpperCase();
 print(sayBonjour);
}
```

Comment: This answer was immensely helpful, Thank you very much for help!  -- I felt the other answer provided was more succinct in its format, although I wish I could select this as the correct answer as well, as the breakdown of what is happening really helped me understand the concept. Thank you again.